# Javascript check if string exists in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays in my program, one contains a list of strings that act as keys, the other contains objects that contain a key as well.

```
let classKeys = ['math', 'robotics'];
let classesInList = [{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className : 'english'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'},];
```

I need to return another array that contains objects like classesInList only if the key (as the className property) exists in classKeys

For example, in this scenario, I would need to check the classKeys against the classesInList and create an array with two items :

```
[{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'}]
```

since english is not in the classKeys, it is deleted from the classesInList.
How would I go about this?

Side Note: I am using react native so I have access to es6 properties and functions.

I am completely stuck in this sense. No matter how simple this seems to be I just cannot find an answer.

Comment: Probably using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). What have you tried so far? What went wrong? Show your best attempt and explain what issue you had with it (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and combine that with [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). What you want to do is to filter the `classesInList` array of objects, and only select those whose `className` value are present in the `classKeys` array.

```js
let classKeys = ['math', 'robotics'];
let classesInList = [{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className : 'english'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'}];

let filteredClasses = classesInList.filter(cls => classKeys.includes(cls.className));

console.log(filteredClasses);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array method and check if the element's `className` is in the `classKeys` array:

```js
let classKeys = ["math", "robotics"];
let classesInList = [
  { key: "WIHUGDYVWJ", className: "math" },
  { key: "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className: "english" },
  { key: "likubqwd", className: "robotics" }
];

let result = classesInList.filter(element => {
  return classKeys.indexOf(element.className) !== -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

using `filter` will filter your array, using `some` to get if some of the values is truthy for your criteria and finally using `includes` to check if the value is included in your classKeys.

```js
let classKeys = ['math', 'robotics'];
let classesInList = [{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className : 'english'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'},];


const result = classesInList
               .filter(c => 
                  Object.values(c).some(val => 
                                        classKeys.includes(val)
                  )
                );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let classKeys = ['math', 'robotics'];
let classesInList = [{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className : 'english'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'}];

let filtered = classesInList.filter(({ className }) => classKeys.includes(className));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in ES6 using `filter`, `includes` and object destructuring:

```js
const classKeys = ['math', 'robotics'];
const classesInList = [{key : "WIHUGDYVWJ", className : 'math'},{key : "qwljdhkuqwdnqwdk", className : 'english'},{key : "likubqwd", className : 'robotics'},];

const result = classesInList.filter(({ className }) => classKeys.includes(className));

console.log(result);
```